# Face ID userFallback not working in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, fallback, face-id

I a implementing face ID in my iOS app. When authentication fails a alert shows containing cancel and try again buttons, cancel button works but try again button not working. How can I edit this button or to be worked  try again button. When i Click on try again button nothing happens if i click on cancel button that is working and even title of cancel button also be changing but no action is applying on try again.I have tried the following code and had a lot of search on internet but nothing found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmlY7.png)

```
func startFaceIDTest(){
    attempted = true
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Identify yourself!"
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply: { 
            successfaceID, authenticationError in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if successfaceID {
                    self.success = true
                } else {
                    self.success = false

                    guard let errorr = authenticationError else {return}

                    switch(errorr) {
                        case LAError.authenticationFailed:
                            print("Failed")
                            break
                        case LAError.userCancel:
                            print("User cancel")
                            break
                        case LAError.userFallback:
                            print("Fallback")
                            break
                        case LAError.systemCancel:
                            print("System cancel")
                            break
                        default:
                            break
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        if let err = error {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                self.success = false
                switch err.code {
                    case LAError.Code.biometryNotEnrolled.rawValue:
                        notifyUser("Your device not enrolled for biometric",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)

                    case LAError.Code.passcodeNotSet.rawValue:
                        notifyUser("A passcode has not been set",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)

                    case LAError.Code.biometryNotAvailable.rawValue:
                        notifyUser("Biometric authentication not available",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)

                    default:
                        notifyUser("Unknown error",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
}

func notifyUser(_ msg: String, err: String?) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: msg, message: err, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: is it possible to put the screenshot of alert?

Comment: yeah sure please see updated post

Comment: i does not have device but i test in simulator. Yes you are right there must be some bug from ios but if you scan the face again and if it match then dialogue will automatically dismiss.

Comment: yes i think it is iOS side bug

Answer (score -1):

```
func bioandpasscodeAuthentication() {
    let context = LAContext()
    var error:NSError?

    // edit line - deviceOwnerAuthentication
    guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) else {
        //showAlertViewIfNoBiometricSensorHasBeenDetected()
        return
    }

      let reason = "Identify yourself!"

    // edit line - deviceOwnerAuthentication
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {

        // edit line - deviceOwnerAuthentication
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason, reply: { (success, error) in
            if success {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Authentication was successful")
                }
            }else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //self.displayErrorMessage(error: error as! LAError )
                    print("Authentication was error")
                }
            }
        })
    }else {
        // self.showAlertWith(title: "Error", message: (errorPointer?.localizedDescription)!)
    }
}
```

try this code